# How can I tell python to edit another python file?

Tags: python, file, edit

Right now, I have file.py and it prints the word "Hello" into text.txt.

`f = open("text.txt")
f.write("Hello")
f.close()`

I want to do the same thing, but I want to print the word "Hello" into a Python file. Say I wanted to do something like this:

`f = open("list.py")
f.write("a = 1")
f.close`

When I opened the file list.py, would it have a variable a with a value 1?  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: First of all you cannot write in file opened in read mode.

Comment: When you open it, it will have the text `a = 1` in it (assuming you open it in write mode).

Comment: be careful with the 2nd code it doesn't close the file

Comment: Don't forget to add the newline at the end. `write("a=1\n")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to append a new line to the end of a file

```
with open("file.py", "a") as f:
    f.write("\na = 1")
```

If you want to write a line to the beginning of a file try creating a new one

```
with open("file.py") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open("file.py", "w") as f:
    lines.insert(0, "a = 1")
    f.write("\n".join(lines))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("list.py","a") as f:
    f.write("a=1")
```

This is simple as you see. You have to open that file in *write and read* mode (a). Also *with open()* method is safier and more clear.

> Example:

```
with open("list.py","a") as f:
    f.write("a=1")
    f.write("\nprint(a+1)")
```

> list.py

```
a=1
print(a+1)
```

Output from list.py:

```
>>> 
2
>>>
```

As you see, there is a variable in *list.py* called *a* equal to *1*.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you specify opening mode, when you are opening a file for reading, writing, etc. For example:

for reading:

```
with open('afile.txt', 'r') as f: # 'r' is a reading mode
    text = f.read()
```

for writing:

```
with open('afile.txt', 'w') as f: # 'w' is a writing mode
    f.write("Some text")
```

If you are opening a file with 'w' (writing) mode, old file content will be removed. To avoid that appending mode exists:

```
with open('afile.txt', 'a') as f: # 'a' as an appending mode
    f.write("additional text")
```

For more information, please, read [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).